# Show a message box while page change in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using tkinter to make python GUI App.

I want to show 'loading ..... ' box instead of page disappearing.

for page disappearing,
i am using a function like this ->

```
 def login(self):
        self.destroy()
        new = tk.Tk()
        st = login.Login(new)
        #open a new object, then initialize new frame
        st.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think you can't remove page disappearing.For `loading....` you can refer to this `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50815547/simple-loading-screen-in-python-tkinter`

Comment: You shouldn't use Tk() to create a new window inside an existing Tk application. Use `Toplevel` instead. Your code should also only have one mainloop